# req.body gets empty when i am uploading files

Tags: node.js, express, multer

i am using Multer in MEAN stack.
i want to upload files with some text fields.
using Postman passing data from "form data" by fields and value.
the problem is when i am passing text field and files simultaneously, the req.body got all value before "files" fields but not getting any value after the file fields.

Comment: Have you tried ``enctype="multipart/form-data"`` ?

Comment: {
  "status": "ERROR",
  "error_message": "Error: Multipart: Boundary not found"
}

Answer (score 0):

There is some example of usage multer in express
https://github.com/expressjs/multer

```
 app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
 // req.file is the `avatar` file
 // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
 })
```